# C++ got pointer instead of value

Tags: c++

I am wondering why the pointer value (324502) is in var signalLengthDebugVar1 instead of the expected integer value (2)?

```
struct ShmLengthOfSignalName {
    int signalLength;
};
//...
BYTE*   pBuf        = NULL;
//...
int main(void){ 
    //...
    pBuf = (BYTE*) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    //...
    JobaSignal sig1;
    printf("Value SignalLength: %d \r\n", pBuf[30]); // 2
    const ShmLengthOfSignalName * signalNameLengthPtr = (const ShmLengthOfSignalName *)(pBuf + 30); 
    int signalLengthDebugVar1 = signalNameLengthPtr->signalLength; // content: 324502 maybe pointer?
    int signalLengthDebugVar2 = (int) pBuf[30]; // content 2
    sig1.setNameLength(signalLengthDebugVar2); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you print the value, you're reading only the single *byte* at `pBuf + 30`:

```
// takes pBuf[30], converts that byte's value to int, and prints it
printf("Value SignalLength: %d \r\n", pBuf[30]); // 2
```

Later, when you cast the pointer and dereference it, you're accessing *a full int*, which is `sizeof(int)` bytes (likely 4). This occupies not just the byte at `pBuf + 30` but also the subsequent bytes at `pBuf + 31`, etc., up to `sizeof(int)` on your platform. It also interprets these bytes according to your platform's byte-endianness (little-endian for Intel, big-endian for most other platforms).

```
// the signalLength struct member is an int
int signalLengthDebugVar1 = signalNameLengthPtr->signalLength; // content: 324502 maybe pointer?
```

Note also that the compiler is permitted to add padding before or after the loation of its `signalLength` field. In other words, you can't assume that `signalLength` will start at struct offset zero, unless you use `extern "C"` or a compiler-specific `#pragma`. And even then, you can't control the endianness interpretation, so if the data was encoded as big-endian and you're on a little-endian machine like x86, the value you see will be wrong.

The bottom line is that in C++ this is not a safe way to decode binary data.

Comment: This means the structure should only contain "char signalLength;" rather than "int signalLength;".

Comment: Thanks! I changed int to char at signalLength and added a var to store the int.